# my .js file doesn't work in a .php file different from my plugin file

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin and a I have to use jquery. 
In my plugin file (call it '**my_p.php**') I register my .js file (**my_js.js**) in this way:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script');
function my_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'my_jquery', plugins_url( '/js/my_js.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_jquery' );
}
```

Code in **my_js.js** is:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         jQuery(document.body).on('click','#button_my_p', function(e){
          alert('hello!');
    });
});
```

my problem is the following: 
if '`button_my_p`' is an element (in my case a button) in *my_p.php* file, it works fine and I see the alert when I click on the button. But, if '`button_my_p`' is an element of another .php file (for example '**other.php**' in my plugin folder), jquery code doesn't work.. I don't see the alert..

What am I missing???

My plugin's structure is:

- *js* folder in which I put **my_js.js**.
- **my_p.php** file
- **other.php** file

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you get some errors in firebug|console web|etc ?

Comment: yes... I get this error: *Unchaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined*

Comment: Now I no longer have that error (I've added a *'echo "<script src='/js/my_js.js'></script>";* in **other.php file**)... I don't get errors... but it doesn't work yet..

Comment: You should not hardcode script resource in WordPress enviroment, the way you use to register and to enqueue `wp_register_script();` and `wp_enqueue_script();` is right.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not care if you have one file or a thousand. It simply searches through the DOM (which may be created by one .php file or by a thousand included) for a matched element.

My advice for debugging this issue will be:
firstly, to check that `my_js.js` is present on the page generated by `other.php` - if it's not - then you use `wp_enqueue_script` incorrectly

Comment: I've checked! but *my_js.js* is not present on the page generated by *other.php*..

Comment: then you need to make sure that all the plugin's pages get the styles and scripts :) also consider reading http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin - it's a good place to start reading about writing your own plugins... this page also contains a @further reading@ section worth reading too